# issue with $filter in angularjs not working with exact search

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs `$filter` to filter data based upon `Id` field.
Its searching for partial of `Id` .

Eg. I have array of 3 objects and in all three objects there is `Id` field having values 4105,41,4159 respectively.

Now when I use  filter to filter data based upon `Id = 41` . Its returning 1st object which is having value 4105.

I am using filter as below

```
var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.gridUserData.data, { Id: userid });
```

It should return object with value 41 as that what I filter for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 You shoud add which comparator u want exact or any.
 $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator, anyPropertyKey)
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `strict` comparison to your filter:

```
// Setting the last parameter as 'true' triggers strict comparison. In other
// words, filtered elements must have their 'Id' index match the input value
// precisely.

var filteredData = 
  $filter('filter')(
    $scope.gridUserData.data,
    { Id: userid },
    true); // <- Enable strict comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the solution. Link to [solution](http://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/163)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>www.W3docs.com</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyModule"  ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type='text' ng-model="filterId" name='filterGender' />

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users | id:filterId" >{{user.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      angular.module('MyModule', [])
       .controller('MyController', function($scope){
         $scope.users = [
            {name: 'Mike', gender: 'male', id: 23},
            {name: 'Jenifer', gender: 'female', id: 32},
            {name: 'Tom', gender: 'male',  id: 14},
            {name: 'Hayk', gender: 'male', id: 14},
            {name: 'Eliana', gender: 'female', id: 28}
         ];
       })
       .filter('id', function(){
         return function(users, id){
           if(!id){
             return users;
           }
           var arr = [];
           angular.forEach(users, function(v){
             if(v.id== id){
               arr.push(v);
             }
           })

           return arr;
         }
       })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```